# backgroundWorker or Thread Cell ProgressBar read DLL And Show treeView

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, treeview, backgroundworker

this question and Answer ->
[C# add child to Parents treeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396225/c-sharp-add-child-to-parents-treeview)

is Stuck Because Volume of data is enormous. How to backgroundWorker or Thread Cell ProgressBar

**Help me implement it with backgroundWorker Thread Progress Bar**

code

```cs
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //// Or by 
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun1));
        th1.Start();
    }

  private void fun1()
    {

          ///   Business_tb_Language  IS ClassLibrary (DLL) return DataTable

            Business_tb_Language businessTbLanguage = new Business_tb_Language();
            DataTable dt1 = businessTbLanguage.bRead();

            LoadTreeView(dt1);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

          ///   Business_tb_Language  IS ClassLibrary (DLL) return DataTable

            Business_tb_Language businessTbLanguage = new Business_tb_Language();
            DataTable dt1 = businessTbLanguage.bRead();

            LoadTreeView(dt1);
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cancel");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }





private void LoadTreeView(DataTable dt)
{
    var dNodes = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();

    foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        string sSublang = dRow["Sub_lang"].ToString();
        string sCode = dRow["code"].ToString();
        string sName = dRow["name"].ToString();

        if (sSublang == "0")
        {
            var tn = treeView1.Nodes.Add(sCode, sName);
            dNodes.Add(sCode, tn);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] arrSubLang = sSublang.Split('_');

            for (int i = arrSubLang.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                string sFindCode = arrSubLang[i];
                var tnLastParent = default(TreeNode);

                if (dNodes.ContainsKey(sFindCode))
                {
                    var tn = dNodes[sFindCode];

                    if (tnLastParent != default(TreeNode))
                    {
                        tn.Nodes.Add(tnLastParent);
                        tnLastParent = tn;
                    }
                    else if (!dNodes.ContainsKey(sCode))
                    {
                        tnLastParent = tn.Nodes.Add(sCode, sName);
                        dNodes.Add(sCode, tnLastParent);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

my code
**Error in function** LoadTreeView(DataTable dt)

**Line**

var tn = treeView1.Nodes.Add(sCode, sName);

** Text Error **

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action.

---

**Read** Business_tb_Language ( IS ClassLibrary (DLL) return DataTable ) **AND Show** in treeView ***BY***  backgroundWorker or Thread Cell ProgressBar

Explain more :

This function  "LoadTreeView (DataTable dt)" and "Business_tb_Language" Correct and true

But I want to implement the BY  backgroundWorker or Thread Cell ProgressBar

---

Thank you.